# Change style of the element in the middle of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, d3.js, colors

i use D3.js and i got another problem.
I got this array `pat`, which let me click 2 nodes and stores the shortest path between those nodes in the array.
Now, i created the middle element of `pat` called `mid`. My goal is, to change the style of this element, lets say into another color `red`.
but i am struggling to find the right solution. Here you can see my code. How, someone can help me to find a solution.

```
var mid = null;

     node.on("click", function(d, i){
        var pat = start && start.pat(d) || []

        mid = pat[Math.floor((pat.length - 1) / 2)];

        node.style("fill", function(d) 
                        {
                          if (pat.includes(mid)){ return "red";}

                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear on what your code does, but here is my suggestion.  As you are creating the elements/nodes, assign them an id:

```
.attr('id', function(d){ return some.identifier }
```

then in your click function, you can select the node that has an identifier equal to the `mid` element.

```
d3.select("#" + mid)
  .style("fill", "red")
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  If you have a better answer, feel free to post it.

Comment: i just upvoted it for you. i don't know why someone downvoted it